# Actionscript3: how to list the pixels of a shape?

Tags: actionscript-3

Checked the documentation but I couldn't find anything. I want list the cordinates of the filled pixels of any shape into an array.

The function would look like this:

> function listShapePixels(shape:Shape):Array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Briefly :

- Convert the shape into a bitmapData with the draw() method
- Scan the bitmap data with getPixel32 to gather the filled pixels and store their coordinates into the array.